# Multicolumn index .. one is Autoincrement

Tags: performance, sqlite, indexing, primary-key, auto-increment

I created the table `patient` in my database :

```
create table patient(n° integer primary key autoincrement, firstname varchar(30),lastname varchar(30)...ect);
```

But in my application ,there is a textfield where researching for patient information by n° or name or surname of patient, I think it is more preferable to index the table by **n°+firstname+surname** to query data faster.

How can i solve it and verify that the n°patient is always **autoincrementing although it is not primary key**
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case have basically designed your primary key to be the surrogate `PatientNo`.  There is no avoiding that.

The solution is to create a non-unique index on `(lastname,firstname)` to assist in name lookups.

Comment: I'd also add that unless this is a hobby/student project FOR THE LOVE OF GOD ENCRYPT YOUR DATA and maybe also consider a commercial database with a full feature set you can use to protect and backup the data.